# When clicking on login with facebook/persona button with angularFire v0.5.0 ($firebaseAuth) user gets redirected immediately to '/'.Why?

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, firebase, angularfire

My problem is simple, everything in this code works as expected except that everytime, I click on login button, I get redirected to '/'. I do not want that. I want the user to stay on login page until they finish authenticating via facebook/persona/twitter and then get redirected to '/content'.

Here is my router/app/controllers:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute","firebase"]);

      app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'landing.html',
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'controller'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/content',{
            authRequired: true,
            templateUrl: 'content.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    }]);



      app.controller('MyController',['$scope', '$firebase','$firebaseAuth',function($scope,$firebase,$firebaseAuth) {


        var ref = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/");
        $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref,{path: '/'});
        $scope.messages = $firebase(ref);
        $scope.addMessage = function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
          $scope.messages.$add({from: $scope.name, body: $scope.msg});
          $scope.msg = "";
        };

      }]);

      app.controller('controller',['$scope','$firebaseAuth',function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {

            var ref = new Firebase('https://mybase.firebaseio.com/');
            $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);



        }]);
```

This (my preferred solution) didnt work either:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope','$firebase','$firebaseAuth','$location',function($scope,$firebase,$firebaseAuth,$location, waitForAuth){
                     var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');
                 $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref,{path: '/'});        
                 waitForAuth.then(function(user){
                     $location.path('/content');
                 })

             }])
```

My div/button looks as follows (I also have similar one  but with 'persona'.):

```
<div ng-controller="controller">

            <div class="facebook-login">
                <a href="#" ng-hide="auth.user" ng-click="auth.$login('facebook')"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i> LogIn with Facebook</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="facebook-login">
                <a href="#" ng-hide="auth.user" ng-click="auth.$login('persona')"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i> LogIn with Persona</span></a>
            </div>

    </div>
```

I have included the following in my html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/module.waitForAuth.js"></script>
<script src="//login.persona.org/include.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I have enabled facebook login and persona login in my firebase forge. Also I have added my facebook app id and secret too. Everytime I click on the login button I get redirected to '/'. waitforAuth I use is here: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/7328023, but if I use it in my controllers, login with facebook/persona buttons do not work at all. If I use waitForAuth, everytime I click on one of the login buttons I get redirected to '/' immediately instead of login popup.

Anyone? :)

Comment: It looks like you're getting routed to / before the login takes place. Try running it like this and see if anything changes:  `ng-click="auth.$login('facebook'); return false;"`, you could also move auth.$login inside a method that returns false or calls event.preventDefault() to generate some more clues.

Comment: I've solved my automatic redirect problem, but ran into another problem, because this now doesnt work: `$location.path('/content');`, after authenticating users get stuck on login page and dont get redirected to /content  :(.. see explanation below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem. Adding the following stops automatic redirect to '/' before login even takes place:

I just needed to add this:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
              });
```

In here like this:

```
app.controller('controller',['$scope','$firebaseAuth','$location','$rootScope',function($scope, $firebaseAuth,$location,$rootScope) {

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
              });

            var ref = new Firebase('https://mybase.firebaseio.com/');
            $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
            $rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
                $location.path('/content');

            });

        }]);
```

However, I ran into another problem, because this now doesnt work:

```
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
                    $location.path('/content');
```

Because after user is finished authenticating they should be redirected to /content (instead of being stuck at login page with login buttons disappearing due to ng-hide (See above)), but it does not matter what I try $location.path('/content') doesnt work.

I tried this:

```
waitForAuth.then(function(){
                  console.log('test');
                  $location.path('/content');
              })
```

But console.log prints out "test" in the console way before user is authenticated, so waitForAuth doesnt seem to work either :/. Somehow waitForAuth fires console.log but it doesnt fire $location.path... Odd.

I even tried doing this (both with waitForAuth and $rootScope.$on:

```
waitForAuth.then(function(){
                      console.log('test');
                      $location.path('/content');
                      $scope.$apply();
                  })
```

But I just get an error that angular $digest is already in progress.

Adding this: `ng-click="auth.$login('facebook'); return false;"` like that, angular throws me this error :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'false' is an unexpected token at column 33 of the expression [auth.$login('facebook'); return false;] starting at [false;].
```

And login buttons become un-clickable...  :(

Ohh dear... me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the URL was always reverting back to the homepage. The problem was caused by a simple mistake in the html syntax:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Log out</a>
```

After I removed # in the href attribute the problem was resolved. Hope this helps others who may experience a similar problem.