# $location.path('/content'); doesnt work, regardless of what I do. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularfire

This is a following up question from this: [When clicking on login with facebook/persona button with angularFire v0.5.0 ($firebaseAuth) user gets redirected immediately to '/'.Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822496/when-clicking-on-login-with-facebook-persona-button-with-angularfire-v0-5-0-fi/20832662#20832662)

I ran into another problem, because this now doesnt work:

```
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
                    $location.path('/content');
```

Because after user is finished authenticating they should be redirected to /content (instead of being stuck at login page with login buttons disappearing due to ng-hide (See above)), but it does not matter what I try $location.path('/content') doesnt work.

I tried this:

```
waitForAuth.then(function(){
                  console.log('test');
                  $location.path('/content');
              })
```

But console.log prints out "test" in the console way before user is authenticated, so waitForAuth doesnt seem to work either :/. Somehow waitForAuth fires console.log but it doesnt fire $location.path... Odd.

I even tried doing this (both with waitForAuth and $rootScope.$on:

```
waitForAuth.then(function(){
                      console.log('test');
                      $location.path('/content');
                      $scope.$apply();
                  })
```

But I just get an error that angular $digest is already in progress.

However, if I do this:

```
app.controller('controller',['$scope','$firebaseAuth','$location','$rootScope',function($scope, $firebaseAuth,$location,$rootScope) {

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
              });


            var ref = new Firebase('https://mybase.firebaseio.com/');
            $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
            $rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
                console.log("root scope");
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    console.log("scope");
                    $location.path('/content');
                });

            });

        }]);
```

console logs out "root scope" and "scope" twice and the timing is perfect: only after user finishes authenticating, but $location.path() still doesnt work and user is stuck at login page/view.

This doesnt work as well:

```
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login', function(){
                    console.log("root scope");
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        console.log("scope");
                        $location.path('/content');
                        $location.replace();

                    });
```

I need some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by removing `authRequired: true` from:

```
$routeProvider.when('/content',{
            authRequired: true, [removed]
            templateUrl: 'content.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
        });
```

and changing the controller like this :

```
app.controller('controller',['$scope','$firebaseAuth','$location','$rootScope',function($scope, $firebaseAuth,$location,$rootScope) {



                $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event,next,current) {
                if (next == 'http://angular.ngrok.com/angularfire/'){event.preventDefault();}
            });

            var ref = new Firebase('https://mybase.firebaseio.com/');
            $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
            $rootScope.$on('$firebaseAuth:login',function(){
                $location.path('/content');
            });

        }]);
```

Changes:

`event.preventDefault();` has to be specific otherwise it prevents all `$location.path();`

waitForAuth doesnt work, because it doesnt really wait for Auth, it fires immediately, hence I have to use `$rootScope.$on`

---

I have also opened an issue on angularFire Github here:

https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/197

And now I have to find another way of preventing unauthorized access :(